# why aren't my properties being serialized, winrt c# xaml

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I've looked at everything I could find about serialization, but not sure why this isn't working. I serialize my List of myMediaInterface objects, which is a base class for the video and song classes. I put the song class below. All the properties that are null are being serialized to the xml file, but all the properties that have values are not. By the time the serialization code is being called, I have 882 songs in the list, and 882 serialized songs are coming out in the xml file, but without any non-null or 0 properties.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Song))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Video))]

public abstract class myMediaInterface
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public String artist { get; set; }
    public String title { get; set; }
    public String album { get; set; }
    public uint trackNumber { get; set; }
    public String genre1 { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan duration { get; set; }
    public uint rating { get; set; }
    public uint bitrate { get; set; }
    public uint year { get; set; }
    public List<String> genre { get; set; }
    public int indexWithinParentCollection { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}

public class Song : myMediaInterface
{
    public String type
    {
        get
        {
            return "Song";
        }
        set
        {
            value = "Song";
        }
    }
    public String path { get; set; }
    public String artist { get; set; }
    public String title { get; set; }
    public String album { get; set; }
    public uint trackNumber { get; set; }
    public String genre1 { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan duration { get; set; }
    public uint rating { get; set; }
    public uint bitrate { get; set; }
    public uint year { get; set; }
    public List<String> genre { get; set; }
    public int indexWithinParentCollection { get; set; }
    public String displayName { get; set; }
}
```

The serialization code:

```
    static async private Task saveState()
    {

        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<myMediaInterface>), new Type[]{typeof(Song)});
            StorageFile musicFile = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync("PlaylistXFastMusicLoading", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            IRandomAccessStream musicFileRandomAccess = await musicFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            IOutputStream outputStream = musicFileRandomAccess.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
            xmlSer.Serialize(outputStream.AsStreamForWrite(), _musicList);
            outputStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception);
        }
    }

async private void loadState()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<myMediaInterface>), new Type[] { typeof(Song) });
            StorageFile sampleFile = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync("PlaylistXFastMusicLoading", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            IInputStream fileStream = await sampleFile.OpenReadAsync();
            _musicList = (List<myMediaInterface>)xmlSer.Deserialize(fileStream.AsStreamForRead());
            fileStream.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception);
        }
   }
```

and the list class initialization

```
    public static List<myMediaInterface> musicList = new List<myMediaInterface>();
    public static List<myMediaInterface> _musicList
    {
        get { return musicList; }
        set { value = musicList; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reimplementing and hiding all inherited member from myMediaInterface. This means that you have the same fields duplicated in base and inherited class. I think you want this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Song))]
public abstract class myMediaInterface
{
    public abstract string type { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public String artist { get; set; }
    public String title { get; set; }
    public String album { get; set; }
    public uint trackNumber { get; set; }
    public String genre1 { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan duration { get; set; }
    public uint rating { get; set; }
    public uint bitrate { get; set; }
    public uint year { get; set; }
    public List<String> genre { get; set; }
    public int indexWithinParentCollection { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}

public class Song : myMediaInterface
{
    public override String type
    {
        get
        {
            return "Song";
        }
        set
        {
            value = "Song";
        }
    }
}
```

Said that, I don't think you need to have a property "type" to identify the type of your objects, you can get the type of your objects with object.GetType().

Comment: Thank you! It works now, guess I have to refresh my knowledge of inheritance.